# Java Android Application Android keyboard(in process com.android.inputmethod.latin) is not responding

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a sample application Android 2.1 google maps(2.1) application that I have. When I run the file, I encounter an error that I am not able to fix and need some help with. I am not entirely sure where the problem could be, so here is my create code in my activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(false);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(13);
        getLastLocation();
        animateToCurrentLocation();
        //added to include overlays in here
        //List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        //Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
        //MapItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
        //GeoPoint coordinates are specified in microdegrees (degrees * 1e6). The OverlayItem constructor accepts the 
        //GeoPoint location, a string for the item's title, and a string for the item's snippet text, respectively.
        //GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
        //OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");
        //try adding another one 
        //GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(35410000, 139460000);
        //OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Sekai, konichiwa!", "I'm in Japan!");
        //All that's left is to add this OverlayItem to your collection in the MapItemizedOverlay
        //instance, then add the HelloItemizedOverlay to the MapView:
        //itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        //itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
        //mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
    }
```

08-04 20:03:05.144: E/ActivityThread(229): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings

08-04 20:03:06.765: E/MapActivity(229): Couldn't get connection factory client

```
 [2012-08-04 17:38:41 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] ------------------------------
    [2012-08-04 17:38:41 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Android Launch!
    [2012-08-04 17:38:41 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] adb is running normally.
    [2012-08-04 17:38:41 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Performing com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity activity launch
    [2012-08-04 17:38:41 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MAPPAPI2'
    [2012-08-04 17:38:41 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MAPPAPI2'
    [2012-08-04 17:38:42 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] New emulator found: emulator-5554
    [2012-08-04 17:38:42 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
    [2012-08-04 17:39:36 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
    [2012-08-04 17:39:36 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Uploading com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
    [2012-08-04 17:39:46 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Failed to install com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
    [2012-08-04 17:39:46 - com.shawnbe.mallfinder.MallFinderActivity] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still quite new with Android so unfortunately I cannot explain the errors, but I get the same errors in my application without them leading to a failed install.

Sometimes restarting the AVD have resolved a failed install for me, but I don't know the cause.

Comment: That solution seems to be temporary.

Comment: Indeed, I hope someone will give you a good explanation; it'll benefit me as well ^^